# VagrantFile config.vm.network

Tags: networking, vagrant, vagrantfile

When my VagrantFile has

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

I execute the `vagrant up` statement

[image]

Will be displayed.

I thought it was because the post was taken， and I execute `netstat -aon` , and there is no corresponding port.

If I delete the statement on `config.vm.network`， Vagrant can be opened normally.

Can someone help me solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the new vagrant 1.9.3 (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395)

you can fix it by adding the `host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` parameter for each of the "forwarded_port" network configuration.

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```